# Simulating a simple SDE (geometric Brownian motion) - problems with Wiener Process

Tags: numerical-methods, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to simulate a simple SDE 
$$dS = \mu Sdt + \sigma S dW_t$$
with $\mu,\sigma \in\mathbb{R}$. When I use the scheme

\begin{align}
S_{n+1} &= S_n + \mu h S_n + \sigma S_n N(0,h)
\end{align}

The results do not make sense. But when I use

\begin{align}
S_{n+1} &= S_n + \mu h S_n + \sigma S_n \sqrt{h} N(0,1)
\end{align}
where $h$ is the step size
$$t_0 < t_1 < ... <t_n \text{ with } |t_{i+1} - t_i| = h$$
This appears to be correct in the simulation, but I do not know why the first one fails. I saw on the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) page that
$$W_{t_2} = W_{t_1} + \sqrt{t_2-t_1}N(0,1) \text{ for } t_2 >t_1$$
"is useful for simulations", but I do not know why this is the case. Is the first method bad for numerical reasons or is there a problem with the method itself?

Comment: The two equations you wrote are equivalent. So probably a bug in your code, I suspect you are confusing std deviation with variance in the random number generator you are using.

Comment: @Tom AHHHHH yes, you are correct. Thank you!